# How to reverse the elements in a sublist?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, reverse, sublist

I'm trying to create a function that reverses the order of the elements in a list, and also reverses the elements in a sublist. for example:

For example, if L = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7]] then deep_reverse(L) mutates L to be [[7, 6, 5], [4, 3], [2, 1]]

I figured out how to reverse the order of one list, but I am having troubles with reversing the order of elements in a sublist. This is what I have so far:

```
def deep_reverse(L)
    """ 
    assumes L is a list of lists whose elements are ints
    Mutates L such that it reverses its elements and also 
    reverses the order of the int elements in every element of L. 
    It does not return anything.
    """
    for i in reversed(L):
          print(i)
```

In the example above, my code would just print `[5,6,7], [3,4], [1,2]`, which is not what i'm trying to accomplish. It's just reversing the order of the lists, the not actual elements in the lists.

What should I add to the code so that it also reverses the order of the elements in a sublist?

[**EDIT**: my code **needs** to mutate the list; I don't want it just to print it, it actually needs to change the list.]

Comment: Thanks for all the help, everyone! I marked Charles answer correct, but I also got a lot of helpful feedback from geo1230 and Stefan Pochmann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks very familiar :). I'm not going to give the whole working solution  but here are some tips:

As you know, there are two steps, reverse each sub-list and then reverse the outer list (in place, without making a new list, so it will mutate the global `L`).

So you can loop through the outer list, and mutate each sub-list:

```
for i in range(len(L)):
    # if L[i] is a list:
        # reverse with [::-1] and update L[i] to the reversed version
# reverse the outer list L, list.reverse() will operate in-place on L
```

Now remember, if you loop through the list like this:

```
for item in list:
    item = 'xxx'
```

You can't change `item` with the above code. `item` is a placeholder value, so changing it doesn't actually modify the list.

You instead need to index the item in `L`, and enumerate can help with this, or you can use the less-preffered `range(len())` as above.

```
for i, item in enumerate(L):
    # do something with L[i]
    L[i] = 'something'
```

**Edit: since there is so much confusion over this, I'll go ahead and post a working solution based on Stefan Pochmann's very elegant answer:**

```
def deep_reverse(L):
    L.reverse()
    for sublist in L:
        sublist.reverse()
```

Notice there is **no return statement, and no print statement**. This will correctly modify `L` in place. You **cannot** reassign `L` inside the function because then it will just create a new local version of `L`, and it will not modify the global `L`. You can use `list.reverse()` to modify `L` **in place** which is necessary based on the specifications.

Answer (score 4):

```
[sublist[::-1] for sublist in to_reverse[::-1]]
```

List comprehension works here.  `[::-1]` is basically the same as `reversed`, but does not modify the list.

EDIT:

As pointed out below, `reversed` doesn't modify the list.  It returns a `listreverseiterator` object

More Edit:

If you want a solution for lists of arbitrary depth, try:

```
def deep_reverse(to_reverse):
    if isinstance(to_reverse, list):
        return list(map(deep_reverse, to_reverse[::-1]))
    else:
        return to_reverse
```

Even more Edit:

To mutate a list in a function:

```
L[:] = new_list
```

Will modify the list in place.

Comment: `reversed` doesn't modify the list either.

Comment: The edit solution doesn't modify `L` either, just returns the reversed version. Check the OP's specifications, this isn't the required behavior.

Comment: To mutate the list, do `to_reverse.reverse()` before the `map` and omit the `[::-1]`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh when I did this, it gave a TypeError: `takes no arguments (1 given)` What's the issue here?

Comment: Did you try to pass an argument to `reverse`?

Comment: I just passed one argument into the function `deep_reverse`.

Comment: Post the traceback?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh So does `L[:] = ____` actually modify the global `L`? I've never seen that before. You can't reassign `L` normally the function.. using `L = anything` will just create a new `L` in the local scope, it won't modify the global `L`, which this function is supposed to do. Interesting that slicing would change that behavior. Though I still think just doing `L.reverse()` is the most straightforward way to modify it in-place.

Comment: @Charles, yes it does.  I had to prove it to myself too. Probably right about `reverse`, I just really like list comprehensions.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to create a function that reverses the order of the elements in a list, and also reverses the elements in a sublist.

Then do exactly those two things:

```
L.reverse()
for sublist in L:
    sublist.reverse()
```

---

Full demo because you seem to be confused about what your function is supposed to do and how to test it:

```
>>> def deep_reverse(L):
        """ 
        assumes L is a list of lists whose elements are ints
        Mutates L such that it reverses its elements and also 
        reverses the order of the int elements in every element of L. 
        It does not return anything.
        """
        L.reverse()
        for sublist in L:
            sublist.reverse()

>>> L = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]
>>> deep_reverse(L)
>>> print(L)
[[7, 6, 5], [4, 3], [2, 1]]
```

Comment: how do I get this to return L?

Comment: @EllaP With `return L`?

Comment: yes, but inside or outside the for loop? i just want to make sure.

Comment: @EllaP Though your function is documented with "It does not return anything". So you shouldn't.

Comment: @EllaP Outside of course. And you could have just tried it, no?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm new at programming so thanks for your patience.

Comment: @EllaP you don't actually want to return `L` (see the problem specifications). Just put the above code in a function, and it should work.

Comment: @EllaP Since you're still trying other things, which don't work, I guess you didn't understand this solution so I added a full demo to my answer. Have a look again.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
L = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]

def deep_reverse(L):
    for i in range(len(L)):
        L[i]=L[i][::-1]
    L=L[::-1]
    return L
```

Comment: @EllaP what do you mean by "mutate"? If you mean re-arranging the list in the way you want then yes. In addition, the way this code is written can be used without modifying it at all, regardless of the number of sublists or number of elements in the sublists. Hope it helped!

Comment: I believe this just reverses the order of elements the sublists. The code also needs to reverse the actual sublists in the list.

Comment: (I deleted the previous comment because I realized that it does mutate the list like I wanted it to.)

Comment: @EllaP <strike>I see you changed your comment.</strike> Did you try the code? If you did, then you should have seen that it prints exactly what you asked in the first place ([[7, 6, 5], [4, 3], [2, 1]])!

Comment: @EllaP No it doesn't really. It doesn't reverse the given list, it just creates a new list with reversed contents. Won't work for your function.

Comment: @EllaP @geo1230 Actually when used in a function, the above code does not properly reverse the global `L`. It will reverse the sublists. But when you do `L = L[::-1]` you are just creating a new `L` in the local scope. You need to use `L.reverse()` to modify the global `L` in place.

Comment: @EllaP @Charles ok i forgot the `def` part... I edited the code after i read your comment. Thanks.

Comment: @geo1230 still doesn't work with the latest edit. You are still just making a new `L` in the local scope with the line `L=L[::-1]`. By adding `return L` that doesn't fix this. Note the specifications: "**Mutates L** such that it reverses its elements ...  **It does not return anything.**" Again, you need to use `list.reverse()` to reverse `L` in place.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Where would I put the `L.reverse()`?

Comment: @EllaP just use `L.reverse()` instead of `L=L[::-1]` and don't `return L`. Although Stefan Pochman has a slightly more elegant solution (once you insert it into a function).

Comment: What does it print out `[[5, 6, 7], [3, 4], [2, 1]]
[[2, 1], [4, 3], [5, 6, 7]]
[[7, 6, 5], [4, 3], [2, 1]]`?  I just want it to print out the last one-- `[[7, 6, 5], [4, 3], [2, 1]]`.

Comment: @EllaP You shouldn't have any print statements in your final code. Just `def deep_reverse(L):` then your code, to modify `L`. Don't `return` or `print()` anything.

Comment: I was just using print() to see what the output is to see if it's correct. I guess I  didn't realize that since it's inside a for loop, it would print as long as the loop runs. Thanks for you help!

Comment: `L.reverse()` and `return L` when used like `deep_reverse(L)` they do return the reversed L correctly.

Comment: This code still isn't working on sublists--it only works on lists with no sublists. For example `deep_reverse([[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3]])` prints `([[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3]])`. However `deep_reverse([[0, -1, 2, -3, 4, -5]])` correctly prints `[[-5, 4, -3, 2, -1, 0]]`. Why isn't it working on sublists?

Comment: @EllaP As I said it isn't mutating the global `L` as it's written above. You don't want/need to return anything. **Just modify `L` in place with `L.reverse()`**. @geo1230 the specs don't want you to return some new list, that's not what is asked for. Yes your code **returns** a new reversed `L`, but it doesn't modify the original `L` like its supposed to.

Comment: @Charles I replaced `L = L[::-1]` with `L.reverse()` like you said. I'm getting the right answers in my python console, but when I submit it on the MIT course grader, my output is wrong (as in the above comment). I don't know if this an issue on the grader's part, or if I'm not understanding the problem.

Comment: @EllaP see my updated answer below. Does that not work? What is the grader complaining about?

Comment: @Charles Ha, I updated my own answer as well, beat you by 19 seconds :-P. I think it was clear, but judging by the discussion here, it clearly wasn't for everyone.

Comment: @StefanPochmann your code was much more elegant than my original solution, and that's gotta count for something :)

Comment: @EllaP sure, happy to help. Be sure to really go through the code to make sure you understand it though, and why the other solutions here didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) to achieve this as:

```
>>> map(lambda x: x[::-1], L[::-1])       # In Python 2.x
[[7, 6, 5], [4, 3], [2, 1]]

>>> list(map(lambda x: x[::-1], L[::-1])) # In Python 3.x
[[7, 6, 5], [4, 3], [2, 1]]
```

Check Blog on [Lambda, filter, reduce and map](http://www.python-course.eu/lambda.php) to know how `lambda` functions and `map()` works in Python.

Answer (score 0):

with functional paradigm and defensive programming:

```
def deep_reverse(L):
    """ assumes L is a list of lists whose elements are ints
    Mutates L such that it reverses its elements and also 
    reverses the order of the int elements in every element of L. 
    It does not return anything.
    """
    # Your code here
    for i in L:
        try:
            deep_reverse(i)
        except:
            pass
    L.reverse()
```

Answer (score -1):

You could make this recursive, so it will work for arbitrarily deep nests.

something like (UNTESTED):

```
def deep_reverse(L)
    """ 
    assumes L is a list of lists whose elements are ints
    Mutates L such that it reverses its elements and also 
    reverses the order of the int elements in every element of L. 
    It does not return anything.
    """
    for i in reversed(L):
          if len(i) > 1:
              deep_reverse(i)
          else:
              print(i)
```

Comment: `len` not `length`.   Additionally, `len(int)` will raise `TypeError`

Comment: You probably want `if isinstance(i, list) and len(i) > 1` or something like that.

Comment: Though since this doesn't return anything or actually modify `L`, I don't think it would work.

Comment: Your code printed a typeError: `object of type 'int' has no len()` Why is this?

Comment: @EllaP see my comment and proposed edit. If you aren't checking if `i` is a list, `len()` will throw an error. Though this won't work either way.

Comment: @Charles Does it not work because I need to mutate the list and the code doesn't do that?

Comment: @EllaP This doesn't work for a number of reasons. But yes, primarily because this code does not ever change `L`. It just loops through `L`, essentially just printing values. Recursion can work for this problem, but not like this. See my answer for a straightforward iterative solution.